# mysql server connection setup with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, lampp

I installed mysql-server on Debian. And also installed lampp on Debian. But in order to run lampp and properly working of phpmyadmin I have to stop my mysql-server running on Debian. This creates two different mysql servers. One belonging to phpmyadmin and one belonging to mysql running locally. Is there any way, so that both phpmyadmin and mysql-server run on same port?

Comment: why did you install mysql-server and then a LAMP stack? the LAMP stack already comes with a mysql server, as you've discovered. You don't need two separate mySQL servers running simultaneously (unless you have some very specific use case), just get rid of one - the one you installed separately would make sense. And then point your phpmyAdmin at the remaining one.

Comment: P.S. The easiest thing might be to purge everything, and start again just with the LAMP stack, and then add phpMyAdmin to it. There are plenty of online guides you can follow in relation to setting this stuff up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant run both mysql servers on same port. The best way is to remove Both MySql and Lamp stack then reinstalling it again.

1.)remove mysql and lamp stack:-

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server.* apache2* php* phpmyadmin*
sudo apt-get auto-remove
```

2.)install lamp stack

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install php5 php-pear php5-mysql
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

then you are ready to code!